# Android: Fill the Progress Bar height of Seek Bar Same as Thumb Size

Tags: android, background, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

Hi have developed a custom seek bar in android and I want the progress bar of the seek bar to be of the same height as of the seek bar  thumb. how can I achieve it  does anyone have an idea how we can do it.
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

> red_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/slider_fill_default_patch"
    />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/slider_fill_patch"
        android:scaleWidth="100%"

        />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/slider_fill_patch"
        android:scaleWidth="100%"/>
</item>
```

> red_scrubber_control.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_thumb_slider" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_thumb_slider" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_thumb_slider" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_thumb_slider"/>
```

> Layout file

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seek1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_progress"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />
```